# Query with Min and Max results from Subquery

Tags: sql, max, min

I need help with a sql query.  I'm using Sql Server Management Studio, and the relevant fields are:

```
Employees.Id

Employees.Name

Events.Employee_Id

Events.DateTime
```

What's the most efficient way to return one record for each employee / date (not DateTime) combination, with Name, min(DateTime), max(DateTime), and the delta in hours for each employee / date combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks so much for the responses.  The question must not have been clear because you both of your solutions were similar, but not what I was looking for.  They did get me to go back and try again from scratch, and I'm not sure why I didn't try this in the first place, but below is returning the results I was looking for.  In my question I had changed the table/field names and omitted requirements I knew I could achieve myself in order to keep the question as simple and readable as possible, which is why this looks so different:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
SELECT e.IdEmpNum,
       m.tFirstName,
       m.tLastName,
       convert(varchar(10), e.dtEventReal, 101) as "event_date",
       convert(varchar(20), min(e.dtEventReal), 108) as "min",
       convert(varchar(20), max(e.dtEventReal), 108) as "max",
       round((datediff(minute,
                 min(e.dtEventReal),
                 max(e.dtEventReal)
       )/60.0), 2) as "hours"
FROM tblEvents e INNER JOIN tblEmployees m ON e.IdEmpNum = m.iEmployeeNum
WHERE e.dtEventReal >= dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), convert(date,getdate()))
GROUP BY e.IdEmpNum, m.tFirstName, m.tLastName, convert(varchar(10), e.dtEventReal, 101)
ORDER BY e.IdEmpNum, convert(varchar(10), e.dtEventReal, 101) ASC;
```

DATEFIRST and the WHERE conditions specifies that only events from this week are returned.  The only problem I'm having now is summing the "hours" calculation.  I'm getting an error, "SQL Server Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery".

Answer (score 0):

Simple way would be using `Join` with `Min/Max` aggregate

```
select e.Name,Min(ev.[DateTime]),Max(ev.[DateTime])
from Employees e
Left join Events ev  --change it to INNER JOIN if you don't want all the employees
ON e.Id = ev.Employee_Id
Group by e.Name
```

Another approach using `Apply` operator

```
select e.Name,oa.MinDate,oa.MaxDate
from Employees e
Outer Apply( --change it to Cross Apply if you don't want all the employees
            select Min(ev.[DateTime]),Max(ev.[DateTime]) 
            from Events ev 
            Where e.Id = ev.Employee_Id) oa (MinDate,MaxDate
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Window functions should be the most efficient method.  Assuming that there is already one row per name and date/time:

```
select e.*,
       max(e.datetime) over (partition by name),
       min(e.datetime) over (partition by name),
       (datediff(hours,
                 min(e.datetime) over (partition by name),
                 max(e.datetime) over (partition by name)
       ) as diff_in_hours
from events e;
```